# Confusion about Pronoun Rules

Tags: grammaire

I came across the following sentence:

> Mon père pense que les jeunes passent trop de temps en ligne mais je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord avec **il**.

Now the word "il" refers to "père." So my question is what is the name of this kind of pronoun. Is it a subject pronoun or is it a direct pronoun? Because were it a direct pronoun we should have used **le** instead of **il**. Also is there a way to determine which pronoun to use in general? Thank you.

Comment: Wherever you came across the sentence it is not correct because "il" is only a subject pronoun. [A lesson about French pronouns](http://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/understanding-french-pronouns). It explains also how to determine direct and indirect objects.

Answer (score 3):

The use of "il" in that sentence is incorrect. It should neither be an indirect nor a direct pronoun.

What *should* be there is what's called a **stressed** or **disjunctive pronoun** or **pronom disjoint** in French.

I would suggest reading about them [here](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/pronouns_stressed.htm).

That sentence should read,

> Mon père pense que les jeunes passent trop de temps en ligne mais je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord avec **lui**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can one follow the following logic: If we can place the name of a person instead of a pronoun and the sentence still makes sense, then use Subject pronouns else use other kinds of pronouns.